# Unable to install VMware Horizon Client on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, python, 18.04, vmware, python-2.7

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.8.0-8518891.x64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
/tmp/vmis.bxQxOU/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: line 76: python: command not found
```

**Edit**:
I followed these steps but still get the original error message;

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python2.7

cd ~/Downloads
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.8.0-8518891.x64.bundle
```

Same Result:

> Extracting VMware Installer...done.
>   /tmp/vmis.bxQxOU/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: line 76: python: command not found

tried 4.7.0 version; same thing.

Comment: check if your python is pointing to the correct python2.7 version of python by `ls -l /usr/bin/python`؛ if it was not then link to it with `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 is not installed by default on Ubuntu 18.04 so you need to install it, but typing the wrong command to execute a .bundle file is what caused the `python: command not found` error.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2.7 
cd ~/Downloads  
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.8.0-8518891.x64.bundle
```

If you get a permissions error from the last command, right-click the VMware-Horizon-Client-4.8.0-8518891.x64.bundle file, select *Properties* -> *Permission*s tab -> *Allow executing file as program*.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below from their documentation:

> a python2 environment on Ubuntu 16.04 x64 distributions, run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```

> to install the gtk2 library.